# How to handle task cancellation in the TPL

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, task, cancellation

Good day! I am writing a helper library for WinForms UI. Started using TPL async/await mechanism and got a problem with this kind of code example :

```
    private SynchronizationContext _context;

    public void UpdateUI(Action action)
    {
        _context.Post(delegate { action(); }, null);
    }


    private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var taskAwait = 4000;
        var progressRefresh = 200;
        var cancellationSource = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();

        await Task.Run(() => { UpdateUI(() => { button2.Text = "Processing..."; }); });

        Action usefulWork = () =>
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(taskAwait);
                cancellationSource.Cancel();
            }
            catch { }
        };
        Action progressUpdate = () =>
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 10)
            {
                UpdateUI(() => { button2.Text = "Processing " + i.ToString(); });
                Thread.Sleep(progressRefresh);
                i++;
            }
            cancellationSource.Cancel();
        };

        var usefulWorkTask = new Task(usefulWork, cancellationSource.Token);
        var progressUpdateTask = new Task(progressUpdate, cancellationSource.Token);

        try
        {
            cancellationSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            Task tWork = Task.Factory.StartNew(usefulWork, cancellationSource.Token);
            Task tProgress = Task.Factory.StartNew(progressUpdate, cancellationSource.Token);
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var res = Task.WaitAny(new[] { tWork, tProgress }, cancellationSource.Token);                        
                }
                catch { }
            }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        await Task.Run(() => { UpdateUI(() => { button2.Text = "button2"; }); });
    }
```

Basically, the idea is to run two parallel tasks - one is for, say, progress bar or whatever update and a sort of timeout controller, the other is the long running task itself. Whichever task finishes first cancels the other one. So, there should not be a problem to cancel the "progress" task as it has a loop in which I can check if task is marked cancelled. The problem is with the long running one. It could be Thread.Sleep() or SqlConnection.Open(). When I run CancellationSource.Cancel(), the long running task keeps working and does not cancel. After a timeout I am not interested in long running task or whatever it may result in.
As the cluttered code example may suggest, I have tried a bunch of variants and none given me a desired effect. Something like Task.WaitAny() freezes UI... Is there a way to make that cancellation work or may be even a different approach to code these things?

**UPD:**

```
public static class Taskhelpers
{
    public static async Task<T> WithCancellation<T>(this Task<T> task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        using (cancellationToken.Register(s => ((TaskCompletionSource<bool>)s).TrySetResult(true), tcs))
        {
            if (task != await Task.WhenAny(task, tcs.Task))
                throw new OperationCanceledException(cancellationToken);
        }
        return await task;
    }
    public static async Task WithCancellation(this Task task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        using (cancellationToken.Register(s => ((TaskCompletionSource<bool>)s).TrySetResult(true), tcs))
        {
            if (task != await Task.WhenAny(task, tcs.Task))
                throw new OperationCanceledException(cancellationToken);
        }
        await task;
    }
}
```

.....

```
        var taskAwait = 4000;
        var progressRefresh = 200;
        var cancellationSource = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();
        var cancellationToken = cancellationSource.Token;

        var usefulWorkTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("WORK : started");

                await Task.Delay(taskAwait).WithCancellation(cancellationToken);

                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("WORK : finished");
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { }  // just drop out if got cancelled
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("WORK : unexpected error : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }, cancellationToken);

        var progressUpdatetask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++)
            {
                if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("==== : " + i.ToString());
                    await Task.Delay(progressRefresh);
                }
            }
        },cancellationToken);

        await Task.WhenAny(usefulWorkTask, progressUpdatetask);

        cancellationSource.Cancel();
```

By modifying `for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++)` limit of `i` I imitate whether long running task finishes before the progress task or otherwise. Works as desired. The `WithCancellation` helper method does the job, although two sort of 'nested' `Task.WhenAny` look suspicious for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with all the points in Paulo's answer - namely, use modern solutions (`Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`, `Progress<T>` for progress updates instead of manually posting to the `SynchronizationContext`, `Task.WhenAny` instead of `Task.WaitAny` for asynchronous code).

But to answer the actual question:

> When I run CancellationSource.Cancel(), the long running task keeps working and does not cancel. After a timeout I am not interested in long running task or whatever it may result in.

There are two parts to this:

- How do I write code that responds to a cancellation request?
- How do I write code that ignores any responses after the cancellation?

Note that the first part deals with *cancelling the operation*, and the second part is actually dealing with *cancelling the **waiting** for the operation to complete*.

First things first: support cancellation in the operation itself. For CPU-bound code (i.e., running a loop), periodically call `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`. For I/O-bound code, the best option is to pass the `token` down to the next API layer - most (but not all) I/O APIs can (should) take cancellation tokens. If this isn't an option, then you can either choose to ignore the cancellation, or you can register a cancellation callback with `token.Register`. Sometimes there's a separate cancellation method you can call from your `Register` callback, and sometimes you can make it work by disposing the object from the callback (this approach often works because of a long-standing Win32 API tradition of cancelling all I/O for a handle when that handle is closed). I'm not sure if this will work for `SqlConnection.Open`, though.

Next, cancelling the *wait*. This one is relatively simple if you just want to cancel the wait *due to a timeout*:

```
await Task.WhenAny(tWork, tProgress, Task.Delay(5000));
```

Comment: `await Task.WhenAny(tWork, tProgress, Task.Delay(5000));` is so simple and straight forward!

Comment: @SergeMisnik: Yes. It gets quite a bit more complex if you want to actually observe a real cancellation token, but if it's just a timeout then it's simple. :)

Answer (score 3):

When you write something like `await Task.Run(() => { UpdateUI(() => { button2.Text = "Processing..."; }); });` on your `button2_Click`, you are, from the UI thread, scheduling an action to a thread poll thread that posts an action to the UI thread. If you called the action directly, it would be quickier because it wouldn't have two context switchings.

`ConfigureAwait(false)` causes the synchronization context to not being captured. I should not be used inside UI methods because, you most certainely, want to do some UI work on the continuation.

You shouldn't use `Task.Factory.StartNew` instead of `Task.Run` unless you absolutely have a reason to. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) and [this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

For progress updates, consider using the [Progress<T> class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh193692), because it captures the synchronization context.

Maybe you should try something like this:

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var taskAwait = 4000;
    var cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var cancellationToken = cancellationSource.Token;
    
    button2.Text = "Processing...";
    
    var usefullWorkTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Dealy(taskAwait);
            }
            catch { }
        },
        cancellationToken);
    
    var progress = new Progress<imt>(i => {
        button2.Text = "Processing " + i.ToString();
    });

    var progressUpdateTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                progress.Report(i);
            }
        },
        cancellationToken);
        
    await Task.WhenAny(usefullWorkTask, progressUpdateTask);
    
    cancellationSource.Cancel();
}
```

Comment: I've read S.Toub's articles a while ago but lately couldn't find them to re-read. So, had to do a random try-error approach... Not a good way to learn. I'll give your code a try.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check `IsCancellationRequested` in the `progressUpdate` Action.

As to how to do what you want, [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx) discusses an Extension method `WithCancellation` that will make it so that you stop waiting for your long running task.

Comment: The important concept in this blog is that you *can't* cancel an operation that doesn't support cancellation. You can only stop waiting for a response. In some cases you may be able to abort whatever is taking a long time, eg by aborting a thread or closing a database connection. In other case you can't, eg you can abort a REST or web service request. You can only stop waiting for a server response. The server though won't know you've stopped waiting